# Java singly linked list node removing loop goes into infinite loop for some reason

Tags: java, linked-list, nodes, singly-linked-list

So this method is supposed to go through the list and remove every third node until there is only one node left, my code is like this:

```
public void printWinningPosition() {
    Node<T> pos = head;
    Node<T> prev=null;


    while (size()>=1){
        for (int i=1;i<3;i++){
            if (pos.link!=null){
                prev=pos;
                pos=pos.link;

            }else{
                pos.link=head;
                pos=pos.link;
            }

        }
        System.out.println("Eliminate suitor #"+pos.data);

        prev.link=pos.link;
        pos=pos.link;
        System.out.println(size());
        outputList();




    }

}
```

the list I'm inputting just consists of objects with numbers from 1 to 7. Right now the output is correct up to the third removal, where it seems to go into a infinite loop or something at the removal code, which is the part after printing "eliminate suitor x".

my console looks like this

```
Eliminate suitor #3
6
1 2 4 5 6 7 
Eliminate suitor #6
5
1 2 4 5 7 
Eliminate suitor #2
```

So it's removing the right nodes and stuff but I have no idea why it stops working when trying to remove #2, the program doesn't stop, but it gets stuck here

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Don't mean to appear cruel, but I think this is one you should figure out for yourself. Do you know how to use a debugger in Eclipse and step through the code? It's getting stuck somewhere between the println() and the `while(size()>=1)` check

Comment: no i actually had no idea what the debugger was but now I'll look it over and see if I can fix the problem, thanks!

Comment: take a look at a tutorial for it. if all else fails you can add more print statements at each step to see what is happening. http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseDebugging/article.html